# Why do we look at $X\rightarrow B$ transition in iodine?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, atomic-physics, absorption

In the classic experiment where one investigates the absorption profile of $I_2$ vapor, we look at $X\rightarrow B$ electronic transitions where $X$ denotes the ground state and $B$ the second excited electronic state. Why is $X\rightarrow A$ not considered?

[image: Electronic level A is skipped. Why?]

Note also that in the figure the eletronic state $A$ has the same limit $I+I$ (both atoms in the ground state) when the internuclear separation goes to infinity $r\rightarrow \infty$, wherears state $B$ has the limit $I+I^*$ indicating one excited atom. See also [2](https://www.shivajicollege.ac.in/sPanel/uploads/econtent/8d90c406af07a0d754b79a687171d6d9.pdf) who claims that $\Delta E(I,I^*)$ is the energy to excite a single Iodine atom. What is state $A$ then if not an electronic excitation?

Comment: Are there selection rules that apply? E.g., based on the angular momenta of the respective states? Like $S\to P$ type of selection rules...

Comment: I do not know a lot about the slection rules that apply for molecules. Online I can't find much that is understandable for me with my limited knwoledge. I am familiar with selection rules for atoms though.

Comment: @Welcome_Green Do you know the symmetry of the initial and final states? For example, do they initial and final states differ by one unit of angular momentum? This is often the case for photon absorption, because otherwise the matrix elements between initial and final molecular states are zero by symmetry.

Comment: @Welcome_Green Can you link to wherever you got the picture from, or post a higher quality image? I can't read all the writing on the picture. Is it from a textbook?

Comment: @hft the image can be found in several books and articles: https://physicsopenlab.org/2022/07/10/iodine-vapor-absorption/ ; https://www.nbi.dk/~phansen/fys8/iodine.pdf

Comment: Regarding the selection rules, it is claimed that there are no rules that apply to rotational quantum numbers, but Delta J = +-1 [https://chemistry.montana.edu/callis/courses/chmy374/I2Shoemaker.pdf]

Comment: @Welcome_Green Two of those references only show the $X$ and $B$ energies, not the $A$. And only one of the references (the last one) seems to provide the Molecular Term Symbols that give information on the symmetry. The "I2Shoemaker.pdf" reference indicates that the ground state $X$ has term symbol ${}^1{\Sigma}_{g}$ (even parity, zero orbital angular momentum) and the second excited state $B$ has term symbol ${}^3{\Pi}_{u}$ (odd parity, one orbital angular momentum). From this I would speculate that the $A$ state's symmetry does not allow for a non-zero matrix element....

Comment: ... But, I can't be sure unless we can figure out the $A$ state's symmetries. If you can find a reference with the $A$ state's term symbol, could you provide it? I don't know if such a reference. The "iodine.pdf" article has a textbook reference in endnote 2 that might be a helpful reference.

Answer (score 1):

> In the classic experiment where one investigates the absorption profile of $I_2$ vapor, we look at X→B electronic transitions where X denotes the ground state and B the second excited electronic state. Why is X→A not seen?

Presumably, if $X\to A$ is not seen, it is due to the [molecular selection rules](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Spectroscopy/Fundamentals_of_Spectroscopy/Selection_rules_and_transition_moment_integral) for photon absorption. (See the section titled "In Molecules" via the link in the previous sentence.)

The symmetry-based selection rules demand that the parity of the initial and final states are different. In particular, for a homonuclear molecular like $I_2$ the parity selection rules demand that (quotation from above-linked article):

> "For homonuclear molecules, the g  ↔  u transition is allowed."

Based on the references provided by OP in the comments to OP's question, we also know that the ground state $X$ has molecular term symbol ${}^1 \Sigma_g$ (i.e., it has "g" or "even" parity). The $B$ excited state has molecular term symbol ${}^3 \Pi_u$ (i.e., it has "u" or "odd" parity).

The $X\to B$ transition is allowed by the parity selection rules, as well as the other relevant selection rules provided in the linked article. Therefore, we would expect to see this transition.

Presumable, the $A$ excited state electronic transistion is not allowed because either it has the wrong parity to allow a transition or it has other symmetry properties that disallow the transition (i.e., force matrix elements to be zero). OP may provide an updated reference for the $A$ state molecular term symbol to confirm this presumption, but has not done so yet.

---

By the way, what do I mean by "matrix elements" and where do these selection rules come from?

The matrix element that is usually considered when calculating absorption is:
$$
\langle F|\sum_i \vec r_i |I\rangle\;,
$$
where the $\vec r_i$ is the position operator of the $i$th electron, and the sum is over all the electrons in the molecule.

Because $\sum_i \vec r_i$ has odd parity, it can have no matrix elements connecting states of the same parity. This is where the parity selection rule and the other selection rules originate from.

Additional information on quantum mechanical calculations of absorption and aspects of symmetry can be found in various quantum mechanics textbooks and references therein. For example, Chapter 11 of [the textbook by Bethe and Jackiv](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201328313) discusses selections rules.

---

**Update** (OP has updated the question)

> Why is $X\rightarrow A$ not considered?

I do not think it is really possible for anyone other than the author of the figure to say why $X\rightarrow A$ was not *considered*. Presumably, $X\rightarrow A$ is suppressed by some selection rules and perhaps only shows up at higher-order in the interaction.

> Note also that in the figure the eletronic state $A$ has the same limit $I+I$ (both atoms in the ground state) when the internuclear separation goes to infinity $r\rightarrow \infty$, wherears state $B$ has the limit $I+I^*$ indicating one excited atom. See also [2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201328313) who claims that $\Delta E(I,I^*)$ is the energy to excite a single Iodine atom. What is state $A$ then if not an electronic excitation?

The state $A$ is an electronic excitation *of the molecule*, but not *of two separated atoms*. That is, the $A$ electronic excitation is (roughly speaking) a combination of two *atomic* ground state orbitals with some phase difference that gives the *molecular* orbital a higher energy than the ground state *molecular* orbital, the latter of which is also (roughly speaking) a combination of two *atomic* ground state orbitals with some phase difference.

The basic idea of "roughly" can be understood by considering a weak coupling $\delta$ between two states that would otherwise have the same energy $\epsilon$. Such a two-state system is described by a hamiltonian like:
$\newcommand{\amat}[4]{\left(\begin{matrix}#1 & #2 \\ #3 & #4 \end{matrix}\right)}$
$$
\amat{\epsilon}{\delta}{\delta}{\epsilon}\;,
$$
which has energy eigenvalues:
$$
E_{\pm} = \epsilon\pm\delta.
$$

In this rough analogy, the energy of state $A$ is $\epsilon+\delta$ and the energy of state $X$ is $\epsilon - \delta$. In this rough analogy, the $\delta$ term goes to zero as the atomic separation goes to infinity and the $\epsilon$ value is the ground state *atomic* energy.

Clearly, as $\delta \to 0$ the energies approach each other, just like the energy of $A$ approaches the energy of $X$ as the separation goes to infinity.

Comment: Following this article [1] (e.g. Fig. 1, the X->A transition is allowed
[1] https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51554119_Least-squares_analysis_of_overlapped_bound-free_absorption_spectra_and_predissociation_data_in_diatomics_The_C1Pu_state_of_I2

Comment: Furthermore, the Pi state is not state B as far as I can tell. Sigma = X (ground state), Pi = A (first excited eletronic state)

Comment: I don't understand. The question in the body our your post was: "...Why is X→A not seen?" But now you are saying it *is* seen?

Comment: I am saying: Why does it seem to be not considered in most experiments (if one looks up I2 absorption profiles, people almost exclusively look at X->B - only in very rare cases (as the example above) mention the X-> A state)

Comment: If that is the question you want answered, then you should edit your post to make that clear. You will also likely have a better chance at getting an answer you like if you move some of the relevant information out of the linked articles and into your actual question post (many people will likely not follow the links and may not have access to the linked material if it is paywalled, and also, the links are subject to rot).

Comment: I should do that. Another, very strange thing I found is the following: In the picture I gave in the question, one can see that the states A and X have the same energy as we dissolve the molecule (r->inf on the x-axis). Furthermore, it says for both A and X: I+I, whereas for state B it says: I+I* with the star indicating one Iodine atom being excited (see also https://www.shivajicollege.ac.in/sPanel/uploads/econtent/8d90c406af07a0d754b79a687171d6d9.pdf). Thus, I get the feeling that state A is not really existent due to an excited electron in either atom, but for a different reason...

Comment: I think what the picture is trying to indicate is that as the molecule is separated, both the states $A$ and $X$ correspond to two copies of the same single state in the atom (the atomic ground state). In the molecule there is something like a phase difference that causes the molecular states to have different energies at finite separation. I.e., the $X$/$A$ states "look like" $\phi_0(\vec r - \vec R_a)\pm \phi_0(\vec r - \vec R_b)$, where $\vec R_a$ and $\vec R_b$ are the nuclei locations. As the separation gets very large, there can be no orbital interaction...

Comment: ...and so as the separation gets large they both go to the same energy value (both just twice the atomic ground state energy value).

Comment: Yes, that's also how I understand it. But this is really surprising to me to be honest -- a molecule where different electronic states are separated and end up in the ground state!

Comment: Another comment why transitions to state $A$ are allowed: Selection rules only impose restrictions on angular momenta (similar to atomic rules) and $A$ is an electronic state

Comment: "But this is really surprising to me..." As an example consider a simple 2x2 hamiltonian matrix $\left(\begin{matrix}1 & \epsilon \\ \epsilon & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$, where $\epsilon$ roughly represents the contribution from orbital overlap between the two atoms. In this rough model $\epsilon\to 0$ is like taking the separation to $\infty$. The two eigenvalues are $E_{\pm}=1\pm \epsilon$. As $\epsilon\to 0$ they eigenvalues converge. Just like the eigenvalues of $X$ and $A$ converge for large separation.

Comment: "Selection rules only impose restrictions on angular momenta..." Not entirely true. The selection rules also can impose restrictions on parity of the initial and final states. Also, the selection rules depend on the interaction approximation. For example, in the "dipole approximation" the transition operator is $\sum_i \vec r_i$, but there are higher order terms that could cause "forbidden" transitions.

Comment: yes, indeed! My key point was that full electronic states cannot be excluded per se by selection rules (but states with angular momenta and parities)